# How to make a CTreeCtrl item centrally displayed?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, mfc

I know that the function `EnsureVisible(HTREEITEM hItem)` can show `hItem` by scrolling the bar of the `CTreeCtrl` control. But sometimes the `hItem` is displayed either beside the top or beside the bottom of the control, which is so unfriendly for users. I want the item to be shown in the middle of the control. Any good solutions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would have to scroll the `CTreeCtrl` manually.  Call `CTreeCtrl::EnsureVisible()` to make the item visible, then call `CTreeCtrl::GetItemRect()` to retrieve the item's current coordinates, and then call `CWnd::ScrollWindow/Ex()` specifying the necessary offset to put the item wherever you want it.

Comment: Very good solution, except the last function, ScrollWindows, I didn't know how to use it to scroll a window, at last I used ::SendMessage(m_hWnd, WM_VSCROLL, SB_LINEUP, 0);